# Why does giving explicit type arguments to a non-generic method or constructor compile?

Tags: java, generics, syntax, arraylist

When instantiating ArrayLists I am used to seeing code like this

```
ArrayList<Type> arr = new ArrayList<Type>();
```

or

```
ArrayList<Type> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

however today I have come across an instantiation of ArrayList that looks like this:

```
ArrayList<Type> arr = new <Type>ArrayList();
```

what is going on, and why does that give an "unsafe operations" compile warning?

Comment: I am not sure how you are getting compile warning instead of compile error

Comment: @AndreiSfat It compiles..

Comment: Can you please mention the java version you using ?

Comment: on what java version you are compiling that code?

Comment: @MarounMaroun confirming that it compiles (tested from the command line, stupid intellij says that it's a compiling error)

Comment: Constructors are not methods in Java. Maroun Maroun's answer provides a more accurate explanation.

Comment: Also, minor nitpick: you should use `List<T> l = new ArrayList<T>()`, the difference being capturing the ArrayList reference in a List variable. It is better to use interfaces, preferably ones that are as high level as possible. Often the implementation does not matter to users of collections, only that it is iterable and know its size.

Comment: @JohnGaughan Ok, that is true... however explicit parameter typing is AFAIK defined in JLS for constructor expressions in exactly the same way as for method expressions (see JLS7, chapter 15.9). Will remove my previous comment as it is incorrect.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Edit:**

Yes, found the reference. See [JLS §15.12.2.1 - Identify Potentially Applicable Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.1):

> If the method invocation includes explicit type arguments, and the
>   member is a generic method, then the number of type arguments is equal
>   to the number of type parameters of the method.
>
> - This clause implies that a *non-generic method may be potentially
>     applicable to an invocation that supplies explicit type arguments.*
>     Indeed, it may turn out to be applicable. ***In such a case, the type
>     arguments will simply be ignored.***

Emphasis mine.

Also see [JLS §15.9.3 - Choosing the Constructor and its Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.3), for understanding how the constructor invocation is resolved. It also mentions that the above mentioned process is followed for resolution.

---

**Original answer:**

Such kind of invocation is often required, when you have a generic constructor, and the compiler is not able to infer the correct type arguments. For example, consider the below code:

```
class Demo<T> {
    public <X> Demo(X[] arg1, X arg2) { 
        // initialization code
        System.out.println(arg1.getClass());
        System.out.println(arg2.getClass());
    }
}
```

Suppose you invoke that constructor like this:

```
Demo<String> demo = new Demo<String>(new String[2], new Integer(5));
```

You would think that the type inference should fail, as the type arguments should have same types. Here we're passing `String` and `Integer` types. But it doesn't. The compiler infers the type `X` as:

```
Object & Serializable & Comparable<? extends Object&Serializable&Comparable<?>>
```

Now, you might want the type parameter to be inferred as just `Object`, then in that case, you can provide explicit type arguments, as in the below code:

```
Demo<String> demo = new <Object>Demo<String>(new String[2], new Integer(5));
```

This is similar to how you give explicit type argument while method invocation.

Now, in your code, you have given the explicit type arguments, but you're using raw type of the class to instantiate it:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new <String>ArrayList();
```

The `<String>` is the explicit type argument for the constructor, and compiler will be fine with it. But the issue is, you're instantiating raw type `ArrayList`, and that is where compiler is giving your unchecked warning. If you change that code to:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new <String>ArrayList<>();
```

The warning will go away. But since `ArrayList` constructor is not a generic constructor, the type argument seems to be just ignored by the constructor. In fact there is no use of that type argument there.

Strangely enough, this also compiles:

```
public static void test() { }

public static void main(String... args) {
    Main.<Integer>test();
}
```

...even though `test()` is a non-generic method.

Comment: @kocko Added a JLS reference too :)

Comment: Reference is for *method expressions*. Constructors in JLS7 does not contain such thing. Or at least I was not able to find that.

Comment: @PavelHoral Well, type argument inference works the same way for generic constructor as it works for generic method. That JLS reference is for why it is allowed to give type argument for non-generic method. I would assume that applies to the constructor too.

Comment: @PavelHoral Another point is, a constructor is ultimately compiled to a method only. So, that also makes sense that the rules apply to them too.

Comment: hmmm.. Now I can again say: Gut Gemacht Rohit! :)

Answer (score 7):

I've just tried:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new <String>ArrayList();
```

And got the same warning (not an error!). Looks like the compiler ignores<sup>1</sup> the generics after the `new` keyword and before the `ArrayList`. It's just like writing:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList();
```

<sup>1</sup> I'm not sure if it really "ignores" that, I'll be glad if someone confirms/correct me

Comment: I receive the same warning as if the generics were left off completely, indicating to me that it is essentially ignored. Perhaps ignore is not the right word: maybe the compiler recognizes it is a generic specification, then discards it because it is out of place. I would be interested to see if the language specification has anything to say about this.

Comment: You might want to report this, as it seems to be wrong behaviour.

Comment: @skiwi Uhmm. The behaviour is mentioned in JLS. So, it's as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The code, it does nothing!

```
int a = new <String>Integer(5);
```

It also compiles but generates a warning of "unused generics".

So basically it is useless but not bad enough to generate an error by default it seems. Either way your arraylist is NOT properly generified here.

Please note that generics are compiled away anyway so at the bytecode level it probably won't look any different. I have looked in eclipse for a way to turn this into an error instead of warning but no luck there.

**UPDATE**

This answer boils down to the same as the other one which is currently at +5, so why is mine downvoted? Please leave a comment if you downvote.

Comment: I totally agree with "leave a comment if you downvote".