# If the signature of a constructor includes the definition of a generic type, what extra responsibilities does that put on users of that constructor?

Tags: java, generics, constructor, signature

I extending an existing project that use generics in a few classes.

I am working on a class called PhiFunction, this class has one construcor which accepts a number of arguments. These include two arguments which I want to force to be the same type, E. These arguments are only used in the constructor, they are not stored as class fields.

I dont want to add this type to the class signature (I want to keep the class definition as simple as possible). The class signature just includes the type T at the moment. To keep the class signature as simple as possible, I added the definition of this type to the constructor signature, as shown below:

Simplified old code:

```
public class PhiFunction<T> {

    ...

    public PhiFunction(
        final MathematicalGroup<?> group, final List<?> baseElements, ...) {
```

Simplified new code:

```
public class PhiFunction<T> {

    ...

    public <E extends GroupElement<T>> PhiFunction(
        final MathematicalGroup<E> group, final List<E> baseElements, ...) {
```

The code compiles fine, and works fine.

The thing which surprises and confuses me now is that, it is still possible to create instances of PhiFunction as before. In other words, the addition of this type definition in the constructor signature does not change how the constructor is used (assuming that users do indeed supply arguments which use the same type). Users can still create instances of PhiFunction, just as they did before, without caring that this type definition was added to the constructor. I expected that users of this constructor would have to define E as being some particular class, but they dont.

I had not used generics in this way before. It seems that adding a type definition to the constructor (or to any method I guess) simply allows a type to be defined, without putting responsibilities on the user of the constructor to define that type.

I guess my question is, if the signature of a constructor includes the specification of a generic type, what extra responsibilities does that put on the user of the constructor?

I have one other related question. Should this type E be added to the Java docs as a parameter? and how? I am sure that it should be documented, as two of the arguments of the constructor must be of that type, but I am not sure how this should be added to the Javadocs.

Comment: as for javadocs: add @param <E> line in javadoc with the description of this type. As for the question itself, I'm now interested in an answer too :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any extra work for invoking a generic method or constructor. Most of the time, the [compiler will be able to infer the type argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html), based on the argument you pass to the method, or from the return type (not applicable here though).

So, when you create an instance of that class like this:

```
MathematicalGroup<Sometype> mathematicalGroup;
List<Sometype> list;
PhiFunction<Double> phiFunction = new PhiFunction<>(mathematicalGroup, list);
```

...the type parameter `E` of the constructor will automatically be inferred as `Sometype`.

However, if you pass arguments that doesn't comply to the rules of type parmeters, you'll see a compiler error, as in this case:

```
MathematicalGroup<Sometype> mathematicalGroup;
List<SomeOthertype> list;
// This will give a compiler error.
PhiFunction<Double> phiFunction = new PhiFunction<>(mathematicalGroup, list);
```

You also have the option to give explicit type arguments, if sometimes type inference doesn't work as expected:

```
// Redundant usage of explicit type argument
PhiFunction<Double> phiFunction = 
           new <Sometype>PhiFunction<Double>(mathematicalGroup, list);
```

Although the above usage of explicit type argument is redundant, but there are cases where compiler will not infer the type that you expect it to. Those are the cases when you pass inconsistent arguments to the parameters that are of same type parameter. Consider the below method for example:

```
public static <T> void fill( T [] array, T elem) {
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; ++i) { array[i] = elem; }
}
```

.. if you try to invoke that method as:

```
fill(new String [5], new String ("XYZ")); // This is fine
fill(new String [5], new Integer (100));  // This is also fine? How?
```

Ideally you would expect the second method invocation to fail, because `String` and `Integer` should not be substitutable for same type parameter `T`. But here's the surprise. The compiler infers the type parameter as the intersection of all the super types of the arguments you passed. So, the type `T` is inferred as:

```
T:=Object&Serializable&Comparable
```

In that case, you might want to give `<Object>` as explicit type argument:

```
YourClass.<Object>fill(new String[5], new Integer(100));
```

*P.S*: Did you know that [you can invoke non-generic methods in generic way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22174022/1679863) Well, generics is full of surprises :)

As for Javadoc, no you don't need to give any information about what `E` represent. Just explain what the paramters `group` and `list` means. That's it. The type parameter and formal parameters are anyways the part of the method signature, and will already be there. Consider for example [`Arrays.binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

To add it to Javadoc:

```
@param  <E>   This represents...
```

This constructor

```
public PhiFunction(
    final MathematicalGroup<?> group, final List<?> baseElements, ...) {
```

Allows any type to be passed to/used with `MathematicalGroup`. Does `MathematicalGroup` have its own generics associated to it already?

If so, then perhaps your new constructor is redundant. That is, even though the original constructor has `<?>`, the generics restrictions of the `MathematicalGroup` class itself already does this enforcement.

```
public <E extends GroupElement<T>> PhiFunction(
    final MathematicalGroup<E> group, final List<E> baseElements, ...) {
```

Otherwise, this is indeed more restrictive, as the original signature allows any type, and this one allows only `GroupElement<T>`, or one of its sub-classes.

As far as how your users use it:

```
MathematicalGroup mg = new <GroupElement<Object>>MathematicalGroup<Object>(groupElementInstance, ...);
```

This is an odd use-case. Usually this generics passing is done with static final utility functions.