# Why does Java allow calling methods with type arguments that don't have type parameters?

Tags: java, javac

I recently found out that you can call a method that has no type parameter with arbitrary type arguments. Consider the following code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test.foo();                         // d'uh
        Test.<Integer>foo();                // yep
        Test.<String, Integer, Float>foo(); // yep!
    }

    static void foo() { }
}
```

Now there are a lot of things that are technically allowed by the grammar but create compiler errors. Why did this slip through?

Also interesting: Calling a method like that creates a warning in Eclipse but `javac` doesn't say anyting, even with `-Xlint`.

Comment: Here's something related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174022/why-does-giving-explicit-type-arguments-to-a-non-generic-method-or-constructor-c

Comment: I knew it will happen sooner or later.

Comment: the linked answer was not very complete. I edited it, so take another look.

Comment: Never heard it called type witness before so no wonder I couldn't find it. Thanks.